# coloring a substring in a label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following label element where I'd like the asterisk to be colored red.

```
<label> Lastname * </label>
```

How can this be done using jQuery, or otherwise?

Comment: Do you accept HTML+CSS as an "or otherwise" answer?

Comment: you might be better off just wrapping it in a span with some CSS style, and skipping the javascript all together. unless there is a specific reason you want this to be done after the page is rendered...

Answer (score 2):

```
var label = document.getElementById('labelId');
label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace('*', '<span style="color:red;">*</span>');
```

No assembly (aka jQuery) required :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with jQuery if you want

```
$('#labelId').html( $('#labelId').text().replace('*', '<span style="color:red;">*</span>') );
```

Comment: nope, the `<span>` wouldn't work if you append it with `text()`

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the text, CSS might be a better choice: http://jsfiddle.net/VwLQM/.

```
label:after {
    color: red;
    content: "*";
}
```

Then `<label>test</label>` will automatically have a red `*` after it.

`:after` does [not fully work on IE8](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after), so that may be an important thing to consider.

Comment: I never said it wasn't -- but you should probably state the browser limitations

Comment: it's a nice example, but :after isn't fully supported by all the browsers yet.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this because IE8's implementation is USABLE in most cases.  Quit worrying about the fringe, fellas.  He's not `text-align`ing anything.

Answer (score 0):

While this might be a little elaborate, it does give you a little wiggle room to markup red asterisks in elements with more than just text inside of it and will likely give you less trouble in the different browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/QjJmT/

```
$(function(){

    var elements = $('label');
    var markup_element = $('<span class="red">*</span>');

    elements.each(function(){

        //wrap the element in a jquery object and get it's text string
            var element = $(this);    
            var element_text = element.text();

        //use regex to use the * as a delimeter
            var other_parts = element_text.split(/\*/);

        //empty the element re-add each part programmatically
            element.empty();
            for( var i = 0; i < other_parts.length; i++ ){
                element.append( other_parts[i] );
                if( i != other_parts.length - 1 ){
                    element.append( markup_element );
                }
            }

    });

});
```

Hope that helps!