# How to find certain text with jQuery and style them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I confused and i need your help how? If

```
<pre>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sir amet</pre>
```

and i want the "ipsum" text colored yellow.

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight a word with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

Comment: you can't highlight a text node, you need to wrap it in another element like `span`

Comment: Also see [if text contains '@' change color of '@'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191076/if-text-contains-change-color-of)

Comment: I guess this could help you buddy .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263239/coloring-a-substring-in-a-label

Answer (score 3):

Try to create a span tag and `wrap` your content in that.

```
$('pre:contains(Ipsum )').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('Ipsum ','<span class="colorClass">  Ipsum  </span>')
  );
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1519/)

Comment: I've upvoted all three great answers to offset mystery downvoter

Answer (score 2):

you can't highlight a text node, you need to wrap it in another element like `span` then use it to apply the highlight

```
$('pre').html(function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/(Ipsum)/, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P3SzS/)

Comment: @downvoter anything I missed

Comment: I've upvoted all three great answers to offset mystery downvoter

Answer (score 1):

Run a little replace function to programmatically isolate your target word, in this case the second word. You could also substitute this for a hardcoded value should you always know what word you are targeting.

**HTML**

```
<pre>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sir amet</pre>
```

**CSS**

```
span { background: yellow; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('pre').html(function(i, word) {
  return word.replace(/\s(.*?)\s/, ' <span>$1</span> ');
});
```

**[Codepen example](http://cdpn.io/kfIuB)**

Comment: If you downvote please example why. Are you a troll? I believe so.

Comment: I've upvoted all three great answers to offset mystery downvoter